# com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.InvocationException: from ContactUsSubmissionService_Proxy.submitContactUs

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

`Window.alert(caught.toString());` in `ContactUs` alerts this exception when I use rpc in my gwt application. can anyone tell me why this is happening so?

The java classes are as follows :-

*ContactUs.java* :-

```
package com.businesstool.home.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiField;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.ServiceDefTarget;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HasText;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextArea;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Hyperlink;
import com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.AttachEvent;

public class ContactUs extends Composite implements HasText {

    private static ContactUsUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
            .create(ContactUsUiBinder.class);
    @UiField TextBox fullName;
    @UiField TextBox emailId;
    @UiField TextBox subject;
    @UiField TextArea message;
    @UiField Button postUs;
    @UiField Hyperlink home;

    interface ContactUsUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, ContactUs> {
    }

    public ContactUs() {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @UiHandler("postUs")
    void onPostUsClick(ClickEvent event) {
        ContactUsBean contactUsBean=new ContactUsBean();
        contactUsBean.setFullName(fullName.getText());
        contactUsBean.setEmail(emailId.getText());
        contactUsBean.setSubject(subject.getText());
        contactUsBean.setMessage(message.getText());

        if(contactUsBean.getFullName()==null || contactUsBean.getFullName().isEmpty()) {
            Window.alert("Please fill First Name/Company Name");
        } else if(contactUsBean.getEmail()==null || contactUsBean.getEmail().isEmpty()) {
            Window.alert("Please fill contact email");
        } else if(contactUsBean.getSubject()==null || contactUsBean.getSubject().isEmpty()) {
            Window.alert("Please fill a subject");
        } else if(contactUsBean.getMessage()==null || contactUsBean.getMessage().isEmpty()) {
            Window.alert("Please fill your message");
        } else {
            ContactUsSubmissionServiceAsync contactUsSubmissionServiceAsync=ContactUsSubmissionService.Util.getInstance();
            AsyncCallback<String> asyncCallback=new AsyncCallback<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String result) {
                    Window.alert(result);
                    fullName.setText("");
                    emailId.setText("");
                    subject.setText("");
                    message.setText("");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    Window.alert(caught.toString());
                }
            };
            ServiceDefTarget serviceDefTarget=(ServiceDefTarget) contactUsSubmissionServiceAsync;
            String moduleRelativeURL=GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"ContactUsSubmissionService";
            serviceDefTarget.setServiceEntryPoint(moduleRelativeURL);
//          contactUsSubmissionServiceAsync.submitContactUs(fName, email, subj, msg, asyncCallback);
            contactUsSubmissionServiceAsync.submitContactUs(contactUsBean, asyncCallback);

        }

    }




    @UiHandler("home")
    void onHomeAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
    }

    @UiHandler("home")
    void onHomeClick(ClickEvent event) {
        RootPanel rootPanel=RootPanel.get();
        rootPanel.remove(0);
        rootPanel.add(new IndexPage());
    }
}
```

*ContactUsSubmissionService.java* :-

```
package com.businesstool.home.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("ContactUsSubmissionService")
public interface ContactUsSubmissionService extends RemoteService {
    /**
     * Utility class for simplifying access to the instance of async service.
     */ 
    public static class Util {
        private static ContactUsSubmissionServiceAsync instance;
        public static ContactUsSubmissionServiceAsync getInstance(){
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = GWT.create(ContactUsSubmissionService.class);
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }


    public abstract String submitContactUs(ContactUsBean contactUsBean);

}
```

*ContactUsSubmissionServiceAsync.java* :-

```
package com.businesstool.home.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

public interface ContactUsSubmissionServiceAsync {

    public abstract void submitContactUs(ContactUsBean contactUsBean,
            AsyncCallback<String> callback);


}
```

*ContactUsSubmissionServiceImpl.java* :-

```
package com.businesstool.home.server;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import vsrd.web.mail.SendMail;
import vsrd.web.mail.Validator;
import com.businesstool.home.client.ContactUsBean;
import com.businesstool.home.client.ContactUsSubmissionService;

import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;

public class ContactUsSubmissionServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet
        implements ContactUsSubmissionService {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6319962734395453042L;

    @Override
    public void service(final HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

    }

    @Override
    public String submitContactUs(ContactUsBean contactUsBean) {
        String fullName = contactUsBean.getFullName();
        String email = contactUsBean.getEmail();
        String subject = contactUsBean.getSubject();
        String message = contactUsBean.getMessage();

        String output = "Successfully sent your message to the admistrator.\nThanks";

        Validator validator = new Validator();

        if (fullName == null || fullName.trim().isEmpty()) {
            output = "Invalid full name, failed posting message";
        } else if (email == null || email.trim().isEmpty()) {
            output = "Invalid Email Id, failed posting message";
        } else if (subject == null || subject.trim().isEmpty()) {
            output = "Invalid subject, failed posting message";
        } else if (message == null || message.trim().isEmpty()) {
            output = "Invalid message, failed posting message";
        } else if (!validator.isValidEmail(email)) {
            output = "Invalid email id, failed posting message";
        } else {
            message += "\n" + "Full name : " + fullName + "\nEMail Id : "
                    + email;
            SendMail sendMail = new SendMail();
            String mailStatus = sendMail.sendMail("visruthcv@gmail.com",
                    "xxx@gmail.com", "Mr.XXX", email, subject,
                    message);

            if (mailStatus == null) {
                String mailStatus2 = sendMail
                        .sendMail(
                                "xxx@gmail.com",
                                email,
                                fullName,
                                "xxx@gmail.com",
                                "Confirmation mail from http://xxx.appspot.com",
                                "Thank you for your valuable message\n\n\nThanks & Regards\nAdministrator");
                if (mailStatus2 == null) {
                    output += ", we have sent a confirmation message to your email.";
                } else {
                    output += ",\n we have received your mail \nbut we failed to send a confirmation mail to "
                            + email + " \nplease give the correct email id.";
                }

            } else {
                output = "Posting failed";
            }
        }

        return output;
    }



}
```

*ContactUsBean.java* :-

```
package com.businesstool.home.client;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ContactUsBean implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2345125743115814903L;

    private String fullName;
    private String email;
    private String subject;
    private String message;

//getter setter methods.....


}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by removing the overridden method `public void service(final HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` from *ContactUsSubmissionServiceImpl.java*. The issue was `super.service(request, response)` was not called in it therefore it could not handle any incoming requests.